# Using .plot() functionality of pandas dataframe in a script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame wit the following properties:

Name: df_name,

Concerned Column: col1

If I want to plot a column, I can execute the following code in python shell(>>>) or ipython notebook.

```
>>>df_name['col1'].plot(kind='bar')
```

However, I want to use the same function in a script and execute from command line, the plot doesn't appear.

The script I want to write looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
.
.
.
df_name=pd.read_csv('filename')

# Printing bar chart of 'col1'

df_name['col1'].plot(kind='bar')
```

Any Ideas how to make it execute from a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you need to import matplotlib.pyplot and to use show method like in example.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_name=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])
df_name[0].plot(kind='bar')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. plt.show() is required.